# AWS IOT : Just in Time provisioning (JITP) supporting additional attributes in Thing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I am using the below link for implementing the Just in Time provisioning (JITP) for AWS IoT.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/setting-up-just-in-time-provisioning-with-aws-iot-core/

If I use the default policy provided in this link, I am able to successfully register the thing.
For the first mosquitto_pub call, I get the connection lost error and the subsequent call was successful, the thing was successfully created in AWS IoT.

I want to extract additional attributes from the certificate, e.g. OrganizationalUnit and want to add it as the attribute to the thing.

So I modified the provisioning template to include this attribute, it didn't work. I am getting connection lost error for all the calls to mosquitto_pub.

Here is the provisioning template string I am using -

```
{
    "Parameters": {
        "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country": {
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName": {
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id": {
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "AWS::IoT::Certificate::OrganizationalUnit": {
            "Type": "String"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "thing": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Thing",
            "Properties": {
                "ThingName": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName"
                },
                "ThingGroups": [{
                    "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::OrganizationalUnit"
                }],
                "AttributePayload": {
                    "version": "v1",
                    "country": {
                        "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country"
                    },
                    "customerid": {
                        "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::OrganizationalUnit"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "certificate": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Certificate",
            "Properties": {
                "CertificateId": {
                    "Ref": "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id"
                },
                "Status": "ACTIVE"
            }
        },
        "policy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IoT::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyDocument": "{\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\": [{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Action\": [\"iot:Connect\"],\"Resource\" : \"arn:aws:iot:*:*:client\/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}\"},{\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Action\": [\"iot:Receive\",\"iot:Subscribe\",\"iot:Publish\"],\"Resource\" : \"arn:aws:iot:*:*:topic\/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}\/*\"}]}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We also made sure the ThingGroups with the required name exists.

Any pointers?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? I am currently having this same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I landed on your post trying to solve this problem for myself. I don't know if this will be of any use to you, but I have 2 comments:

**The Right Order:**

I found that I had to create the ThingGroups and ThingTypeName in advance of registering the certificate, although failing to do so did not return any error. I note that you did this already, but just make sure you haven't changed any group or type name(s) (I did so absentmindedly and it stung me).

Specificaly, it did not work when I did `aws iot register-ca-certificate` first (with the ThingGroups & ThingTypeName in the provisioning template), then created groups & types and lastly started to connect devices. My advice is to start again carefully and go through it in order: create groups&types; register ca cert. Then attempt to connect.

**The Policy Format:**

As a starting point, I used the following formats for the policy resources. The * were useful for isolating the source of formatting problems. I found editing the policy JSON file directly in the IoT console was the most efficient way to figure out what was wrong.

For iot:Publish, iot:Receive & iot:Subscribe, resource =

```
"arn:aws:iot:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:*/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*
```

And for the iot:Connect, resource =

```
"arn:aws:iot:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:*/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}
```

Having done that, JITP process started to work. Best of luck.